# newtonsoft.json ShouldSerialize property working but ShouldDeserialize not working

Tags: c#, json.net, asp.net-core-3.1

In my code I want to use ShouldDeserialize method to make my response more cleaner, but  ShouldDeserialize{Property} method is not visible for deserialize method. In below code ShouldSerializeItems predicate works.

```
public class ItemsContainer
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public IEnumerable<Item> Items{ get; set; }
    //Working
    public bool ShouldSerializeItems()
    {
        return !Items.All(x =>
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.ItemName) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.ItemId));
    }
    // Not working
    public bool ShouldDeserializeItems()
    {
        return !Items.All(x =>
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.ItemName) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.ItemId));
    }
}
```

And call deserialize:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ItemsContainer>(json);
```

In newtonsoft documentation both serialize and deserialize predicate are documented:

- https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonProperty_ShouldDeserialize.htm
- https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonProperty_ShouldSerialize.htm

Comment: You have to post your json too.

Comment: Am I missing something, or are both Methodes equal? There is no Newtonsoft Methods called

Comment: `ShouldDeserialize` is not implemented
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35502152/conditional-serialization-deserialization-of-object-properties-with-json-net

Comment: @Charles Are you sure that it has not been implemented in the last five years?

Comment: @PeterCsala it's not working with any property i tested. So i would say it's not

Comment: That's right, checking for a property named ShouldDeserializeXXX() and automatically calling it was never implemented, probably because XmlSerializer only ever had support for ShouldSerializeXXX(), and the Json.NET functionality was modeled on that. See: [Conditional serialization/deserialization of object properties with json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35502152/3744182). The infrastructure is there, so you can do it yourself if you need to.

Comment: Now that I look at your code, your method `ShouldDeserializeItems()` assumes that the `Items` **have already been deserialized**.  Json.NET's `ShouldDeserialize` function is called **before** deserialization, not after.  You should use an [`[OnDeserialized]`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationCallbacks.htm) callback to clear out unwanted items after deserialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking for a property named named `ShouldDeserialize*()` and automatically calling it was never implemented by Json.NET. See: *[Conditional serialization/deserialization of object properties with json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35502152/3744182)*.  The infrastructure is there, so you could do it yourself by implementing a [custom contract resolver](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/contractresolver.htm#CustomIContractResolverExamples) that overrides [`DefaultContractResolver.CreateProperty()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver_CreateProperty.htm) and sets [`JsonProperty.ShouldDeserialize`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonProperty_ShouldDeserialize.htm).

That being said, it appears that your method `ShouldDeserializeItems()` assumes that the `Items` have already been deserialized, then filters them out based on some custom logic.  Json.NET's `JsonProperty.ShouldDeserialize` predicate is called **before** deserialization, not after.  When it returns `true` the JSON property is **skipped** with no ability to examine the contents, and thus cannot be used here.

**Instead**, you should use an [`[OnDeserialized]`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationCallbacks.htm) callback to clear out unwanted items after deserialization:

```
[System.Runtime.Serialization.OnDeserialized]
private void OnDeserializedMethod(System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext context)
{       
    if (Items != null && Items.All(x =>
        string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.ItemName) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.ItemId)))
        Items = new List<Item>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

But when you are about to deserialize the Items property of the ItemContainer there is likely nothing in the Items property yet. You may not need this predicate because if the ShouldSerialize is working correctly you will never have junk data to deserialize.