# How does JSON.NET set a get-only IEnumerable<T> property?

Tags: c#, json.net

In the following sample, both `foo` and `deserializedFoo` variables have a fully-populated `Values` property. A private, no-op constructor is given the `[JsonConstructor]` attribute to avoid constructor value mapping from the public constructor.

In spite of this, it appears that JSON.NET is able to set the value of the get-only property if its backing field is assigned to an empty list during construction.

I am unable to find any mention of this behaviour in the JSON.NET documentation. Can anyone explain this behaviour?

```cs
void Main()
{
    var foo = new Foo(new [] { "One", "Two", "Three" });
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo);
    var deserializedFoo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(json);
}

class Foo
{
    private readonly List<string> _values;

    public Foo(IEnumerable<string> values)
    {
        _values = values.ToList();
    }

    [JsonConstructor]
    private Foo()
    {
        _values = new List<string>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> Values => _values;
}
```

Comment: I am guessing it's done via reflection magic...

Comment: I think you can find it somewhere from [here](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/DefaultContractResolver.cs#L1663), although I can't quite see how/where :)

Comment: What did you expect to happen here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure where this is documented (if at all) but during deserialization of an object, if a reference-type member is already allocated, Json.NET will re-use the existing member instance rather than allocating a new one.  Then it will populate the JSON into the member using the **actual, concrete** type of the member's value -- not the declared type.  In your case the actual, concrete type of the object returned by `Values` is `List<string>` -- which Json.NET is able to populate.

If I change `Values` to actually return a read-only enumerable like so:

```
public IEnumerable<string> Values => _values.AsReadOnly();
```

Then `Values` is not populated -- demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GjkTix).

On the other hand if I change the declared type of `Values` to be `object` like so:

```
public object Values => _values;
```

It *is* populated.  Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/aTtTKB).

And as a final demonstration, if I modify your `Foo` model to have some additional pre-allocated, read-only property `Bar` that is only declared as `object` like so:

```
class Foo
{
    private readonly List<string> _values;
    private readonly Bar _bar = new Bar();

    public Foo(IEnumerable<string> values)
    {
        _values = values.ToList();
    }

    [JsonConstructor]
    private Foo()
    {
        _values = new List<string>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> Values { get { return _values; } }

    public object Bar { get { return _bar; } }
}

public class Bar
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
}
```

Then the actual object referred to by the property will be successfully populated:

```
var json = @"{""Values"":[""One"",""Two"",""Three""],""Bar"":{""Property1"":""Test""}}";
var deserializedFoo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(json);
Assert.IsTrue(deserializedFoo.Values.Count() == 3 && ((Bar)deserializedFoo.Bar).Property1 == "Test"); // No Assert
```

Demo fiddle #3 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/G06V3l).

So what are your options, if you don't want this behavior?

Firstly, you could wrap your collection in a read-only wrapper as shown above.  This is not a bad idea in general, because it prevents consumers of your `Foo` type from simply casting `Values` to a `List<T>` and modifying it.

Secondly, you could deserialize using `ObjectCreationHandling.Replace`.  When this setting is enabled, Json.NET will always allocate new values for pre-allocated read/write properties -- and skip over pre-allocated read-only properties.  Demo fiddle #4 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/G7pvAv).  Note this prevents population of read-only member referring to any .Net reference type, not just collections.

Thirdly, you could adopt the approach from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56885301/3744182) to *[Serialize Property, but Do Not Deserialize Property in Json.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31731320/3744182)* by [Pavlo Lissov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7027460/pavlo-lissov) and create a custom contract resolver that sets [`JsonProperty.ShouldDeserialize`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonProperty_ShouldDeserialize.htm) to a predicate returning false for properties that should not get deserialized.

Comment: Really comprehensive answer. Thank you.