# How to make JsonPropertyAttribute not to deserialize menber with private set

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a class

```
public class Event{
[JsonProperty("event_type")] public string EventType { get; private set; }
}
```

when I deserialize it with

```
Event event = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Event>("{'event_type':'started'}"
```

Field EventType is feed with value "started".
But I don't expect this cause it is a "get;private set" menber, which should not be deserialized but can be serialized as I expect.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: There is the `JsonIgnoreAttribute` that you can use to mark your properties with. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: What would be the purpose of serializing a field without intent to deserialize it?

Comment: Take a look at [Serialize Property, but Do Not Deserialize Property in Json.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31731320/3744182).

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like a `JsonConverter` ([see here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverterGeneric.htm))
That would let you override how the object was created so you could use a constructor or a static method to init the private set property. Although I have to say the use case for this is pretty rare. Perhaps elaborate on why you need that property to be a private set and we can provide more help.