# .NET Newtonsoft Allow property to be only serialised

Tags: c#, asp.net, json.net

I have implemented the answer from this (rather old) question https://stackoverflow.com/a/31732029/4180176 but it doesn't seem to work for me and I can't figure out why.

I can indeed see that `property.Writable` gets set to false. The property I mark as not serializable gets put as the last field in the output json but is always present

**Startup.cs**

```
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(opt =>
{
  opt.UseMemberCasing();
  opt.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new NewtonsoftContractResolver();
});
```

**Contract Resolver**

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class DoNotSerializeAttribute : Attribute
{

}

public class NewtonsoftContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);

        if (property is not null && property.Writable)
        {
            var attributes = property.AttributeProvider.GetAttributes(typeof(DoNotSerializeAttribute), true);

            if (attributes is not null && attributes.Count > 0)
            {
                    property.Writable = false;
            }
        }    
        return property;
    }
}
```

**Attribute Usage**

```
public class LeaderboardUser : RankedObject
{
    [JsonProperty("UserID")]
    [DoNotSerialize]
    public string UserID { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: try simple jsonignore. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-ignore-properties?pivots=dotnet-6-0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

serialization

```
var leaderBoardUser = new LeaderboardUser { UserID = "userId", UserName = "userName" };
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(leaderBoardUser);
```

result

```
{"UserID":"userId","UserName":"userName"}
```

deserialization

```
leaderBoardUser = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LeaderboardUser>(json);
```

result

```
UserID  null
UserName    userName
```

class

```
public partial class LeaderboardUser
{
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [JsonConstructor]
    public LeaderboardUser(string UserId)
    {

    }
    public LeaderboardUser()
    {

    }
}
```